# Testing Smart Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, gas, testing, ethereum-classic

We all know a smart contract is a normal piece of code which can have intended and unintended bugs. DAO attack is such an example where a bug has led to a heavy loss. Suppose I want to check what all properties can be there which a smart contract should satisfy in order to call it as safe. I have seen that there are many projects already going on where **FORMAL VERIFICATION** is being used to achieve the exact specification but I am not talking about those things. I am asking for some safe properties which can ensure this safety.

**For example**, we know that using **CALL** function to transfer ethers to a contract address can be a potential vulnerability that can be exploited if not handled properly.

**So what all these properties can be?**

Comment: If you're looking for safety best practices, here's a resource https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Safety

Comment: @MiguelMota yeah I have an idea about that but I am basically implementing a system where I want these properties to be the checkpoints so that I can analyze whether my program has satisfied these general key features or not

Comment: The DOA attack is not a bug, just the developer forgot to set security (use modifiers).

Comment: @Andromelus Yeah sorry for saying that way but yes there was bad coding practice which was followed.

Comment: solidity is silly

Answer (score 1):

"Tests Cant Prove The Absence Of Bugs"

This is a fundamental law of testing.